# How to use telegram api package in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0, php-telegram-bot

I tried to use [PHP telegram bot](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core) in my CakePHP 3 website, but encountered many problems.

**done**

I ran "composer require longman/telegram-bot" and copied package to "plugins" folder.

and then "bin/cake plugin load longman/telegram-bot".

**questions**

1. Where I must put the package and why? *vendor* or *plugins*

2. How to call package methods in URL?

I added "index" method to "telegram-bot/src/Telegram.php" and tried this snippet code in my "Template/Users/index.ctp".

`echo $this->Html->link('telegram', ['plugin' => 'longman/telegram-bot', 'controller' => 'telegram', 'action' => 'index']);`

that results

`Error: A route matching "array ( 'plugin' => 'longman/telegram-bot', 'controller' => 'telegram', 'action' => 'index', '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.`

3. What I must add to "routes.php"?

4. How can I use "telegram-bot/src/Telegram.php" methods in my controllers and models.

5. Is there anything else that must be observed?

Thanks.

Comment: Telegram bot isn't a [cakephp plugin](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html), so `Plugin::load('longman/telegram-bot')` will have no effect. The route's `controller` key is expecting the name of an `instanceof` [Controller](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html) -specifying an arbitrary class will have no effect. You would use this class the same way you would use any class (inside or outside of a controller): `$telegram = new Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram(...);`

Comment: Thank you. very valuable guidance. I was confused yesterday. its done.

Comment: @mitra razmara Please share your solutions.