# Manage other class output in CakePHP 3 controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using a PHP (not CakePHP) vendor in my app.

I put  [vendor](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core) folder in "src/controller" and included it in "src/Controller/TelegramsController.php" set() method.

```
public function set() {
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $API_KEY = 'api key';
    $BOT_NAME = 'bot name';
    $hook_url = 'hook url';
    try {
        // Create Telegram API object
        $telegram = new Telegram($API_KEY, $BOT_NAME);

        // Set webhook
        $result = $telegram->setWebhook($hook_url);
        if ($result->isOk()) {
            echo $result->getDescription();
        }
    } catch (Longman\TelegramBot\Exception\TelegramException $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

When I call set() method, Telegram class displays response before CakePHP renders the view. And CakePHP displays this warning.

`Unable to emit headers.`

How can I manage Telegram class streaming out functions to display in CakePHP view (not before view)?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you include composer-compatible libraries into a composer-compatible project, instead you `composer require` them and rely on the main autoloader included by the CakePHP application:

```
$ composer require longman/telegram-bot
```

Please read up on how [**composer**](https://getcomposer.org) works.

That being said, you are overwriting an existing controller method, the `Controller::set()` method is used to register data for use in view templates. Choose a different name for your controller action method, and use the existing `set()` method to pass data to your view template if required, alternatively return a properly prepared response object. In any case, do not echo data in controller actions!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Controller Actions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#controller-actions)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Interacting with Views](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Setting the Body](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-the-body)**
- **[How to output custom HTTP body contents with CakePHP 3.4? Echoing causes "Unable to emit headers" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable)**

Comment: Thank you. [I tried "composer require longman/telegram-bot" but was not successful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106107/how-to-use-telegram-api-package-in-cakephp-3?)

Comment: Sorry. I thought "telegram class" echoed the message. consider "telegram class" echoes some messages. Is there any way to wrap the messages if an external class (like telegram) echoes messages?